# Empty cells and large SE's in logistic regression?

Tags: regression, logistic, multiple-regression

With data of size N = 550, I have run multivariate logistic regression in order to regress dichotomous variable of woman postnatal depression (yes/no) on 9 predictors, namely:

Area of residence: a categorical variable containing 13 areas, the frequency of each ranges from 7 (lowest) to 166.
Using antibiotic (yes/no)
Physical activity level: 3 ordinal levels (none, moderate, high)
Visiting gym level (no gym, sometimes, frequently)
Receiving aid in taking care of the baby (from mother, maid, etc.): no aid, sometimes, constant aid
Having physical activity area at home (yes/no)
last birth difficulty level (5-point scale)
income level: 9 ordinal categories with frequencies ranging from 13 to 134
baby age (days): a continuous variable
I ran forward method of selection (conditional), and the remaining at the last step are shown in the picture below:
[image]

The results show big SE's (could even have a size that is one third or one half of the predicted B).

The constant terms is so large, and its exponential value is around 6! this means that much of the model rely on the constant! and the constant was significant too.

I then tried to reduce the size of family income and last birth difficulty by dichotomizing them and the results are not much better. See picture below:

[image]